# How to interpret impulse response analysis in VAR when using standardized variables?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, vector-autoregression, standardization, impulse-response

How to interpret impulse response analysis when using standardized variables (ie., subtracting the mean and divide by standard deviation) in vector autoregression analysis? The reason why I standardized variables is because I am using variables with different measurement units.

I want to add that the size of the positive shock is the average of the stochastic volatility during the study period. (ie., not the usual 1 standard deviation).

Comment: maybe it is late but Walters Enders explains it in https://wenders.people.ua.edu/uploads/2/6/3/8/26382715/rats_programming_manual_w_enders.pdf